# Socket-io falla en Angular 12

Tags: angular, socket, socket.io, websocket, angular12

tengo un inconveniente al integrar Socket IO en Angular 12, normalmente uso socket.io-client para realizar la comunicación entre el front Angular y el Websocket, pero con la última versión de Angular no lo he logrado, no se presenta error pero en el log del socket me sale el estado de conexón exitosa una y otra vez, no emite ni recibe mensajes, solo conecta indefinidamente.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el código que uso en el servicio es el siguiente:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { io, Socket } from 'socket.io-client';
import { DefaultEventsMap } from 'socket.io-client/build/typed-events';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class WebsocketSecureKeyService {
  socket!: Socket<DefaultEventsMap, DefaultEventsMap>;
   constructor() { }
  setupSocketConnection() {
    this.socket = io(environment.serverSocket);
    this.socket.emit('join-room', '123456');
  }

  disconnect() {
    if (this.socket) {
        this.socket.disconnect();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

me paso el mismo problema; el tema era en ambos lados tanto en el servidor de node y en mi angular:

***1.- En el caso de Node tuve que cambiar varias cosa utiliza esto Node:***

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const chalk = require('chalk');
const cors = require('cors');

app.use(cors());
const options = {
  cors: {
    origin: 'http://localhost:4200',
  },
};

const server = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server, options);



app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!');
});



io.on('connection', function (socket) {

  const handshake = socket.id;

  let { nameRoom } = socket.handshake.query;
  console.log(`${chalk.green(`Nuevo dispositivo: ${handshake}`)} conentado a la ${nameRoom}`);
  socket.join(nameRoom)

  socket.on('evento', (res) => {
    // Emite el mensaje a todos lo miembros de las sala menos a la persona que envia el mensaje   
    socket.to(nameRoom).emit('evento', res);

  })


  socket.on('disconnect', function () {
    console.log('user disconnected');
  });
});

server.listen(5000, function () {
  console.log('\n')
  console.log(`>> Socket listo y escuchando por el puerto: ${chalk.green('5000')}`)
})
```

***ANGULAR***

**socket-web.service.ts**

```
import { EventEmitter, Injectable, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { Socket } from 'ngx-socket-io';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SocketWebService extends Socket {

  @Output() outEven: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  constructor() {
    super({
      url: 'http://localhost:1002',
      options: {
        query: {
          nameRoom: 'xxxx'
        },
      }
    })
    this.listen();
  }

  listen = () => {
    this.ioSocket.on('evento', (res: any) => this.outEven.emit(res));   
  }
  emitEvent = (payload = {}) => {
    this.ioSocket.emit('evento', payload)

  }
}
```

**pantalla.component.ts**

```
import { SocketWebService } from './services/socket-web.service';

.........
export class VMonitoreoComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(

private socketWebService: SocketWebService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.socketWebService.outEven.subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res);
    })
  }
  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.socketWebService.disconnect();
  }
}
```

Todo esto fue gracias a este curso: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gW3Fd-J6LgU

https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCgrIGp5QAnC0J8LfNJxDRDw

Answer (score 0):

me paso lo mismo, lo resolví revisando la documentación del paquete ngx-socket-io, en esta documentación habla sobre como usar el paquete y que versiones de angular, socketio.io y ngx-socket-io se deben de usar para que todo funcione bien.

Make sure you're using the proper corresponding version of socket.io on the server.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-socket-io

esa tabla muestra que versiones son "compatibles", por ejemplo yo trabajo con angular 13 y use la versión del paquete 4.2.0 y de socket.io 4.0.0.

Espero te sirva.